# Как копировать положение объекта unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким образом можно скопировать положение объекта через GameObject.Find("name1") таким образом чтоб после запуска скрипта в это же положение телепортировался другой GameObject вне зависимости где находится первый

Я пробовал сделать `GameObject.Find("name1").transform.position(GameObject.Find("name2").transform.position);`

или же `GameObject.Find("name1").transform.position = GameObject.Find("name2").transform.position;`

но это тоже не помогло

Нашёл способ через `transformTarget`, но либо я упорно не понимаю как он работает, либ устарел и не поддерживается

Comment: `но это тоже не помогло` - поточнее. Как не помогло: ошибка, не работает вообще, работает неверно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном фрагменте кода, объект 1 телепортируется к объекту 2

```
GameObject 1;
GameObject 2;

void Start(){
1 = GameObject.Find("name1").gameObject;
2 = GameObject.Find("name2").gameObject;

1.transform.position = 2.transform.position;
}
```